# Application Server Administration job failed for service instance Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance

Tags: 2010, search, events

I'm running a SharePoint 2010 environment consisting of one Web Front End Server and one Database Server.

When I view the event logs on the Web Server I see several errors with the Event ID 6482:

> Application Server Administration job failed for service instance
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance
>   (a8295c81-5a72-4c61-9d59-82bbd2e3a8c0).
>
> Reason: An update conflict has occurred, and you must re-try this
>   action. The object SearchDataAccessServiceInstance was updated by
>   DOMAIN\SHP_SQL_Config, in the OWSTIMER (4788) process, on machine
>   SERVERNAME.  View the tracing log for more information about the
>   conflict.
>
> Technical Support Details:
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUpdatedConcurrencyException: An
>   update conflict has occurred, and you must re-try this action. The
>   object SearchDataAccessServiceInstance was updated by
>   DOMAIN\SHP_SQL_Config, in the OWSTIMER (4788) process, on machine
>   SERVERNAME.  View the tracing log for more information about the
>   conflict.    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.Synchronize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ApplicationServerJob.ProvisionLocalSharedServiceInstances(Boolean
>   isAdministrationServiceJob)

What actions can I do to resolve these recurring errors in my Event Viewer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I managed to fix this error by following these steps:

1. Stop the Windows SharePoint Services Timer service (Found in Windows Services)
2. Navigate to the cache folder
   In Windows Server 2008, the configuration cache is in the following location:
   Drive:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config
3. Locate the GUID folder that has the file "Cache.ini"
   (Note: The Application Data folder may be hidden. To view the hidden folder, change the folder options as required)
4. Back up the Cache.ini file (and the other xml files)
5. Delete all the XML configuration files in the GUID folder. Do this so that you can verify that the GUID folder is replaced by new XML configuration files when the cache is rebuilt.
   Note When you empty the configuration cache in the GUID folder, make sure that you do not delete the GUID folder and the Cache.ini file that is located in the GUID folder.
6. Double-click the Cache.ini file
7. On the Edit menu, click Select All. On the Edit menu, click Delete. Type 1, and then click Save on the File menu. On the File menu, click Exit.
8. Start the Windows SharePoint Services Timer service

*Note The file system cache is re-created after you perform this procedure. Make sure that you perform this procedure on all servers in the server farm.*

*Make sure that the Cache.ini file in the GUID folder now contains its previous value. For example, make sure that the value of the Cache.ini file is not 1.*

Source: http://www.social-point.com/sharepoint-2010-event-id-6482-application-server-administration-job-failed-for-service-instance-microsoft-office-server-search-administration-searchserviceinstance

Comment: Folder path can be access easily with win+R  and "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config\"(remove Quotes)