# Search Application Topology is keep loading in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

I have Windows server 2008, SP2010 as one farm. I successfully configured the search service but the search topology is keep loading and annoying with the same error:- Please read below for more details:

Application Management-->Service Applications-->Manage service application.
Once i click on Manage service application i can view the list of services, and am selecting Search Service Application
I can view System Status, Crawl History with no items and my Search Application Topology is keep Loading.

On my left side, under Crawling all the following links "Content Sources" "Crawl Rules" "Crawl Log" "Serve Name Mappings" "Host distribution rules" "File Types" are all throwing the same below error:-

> System.InvalidOperationException: The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component. Verify that the administration component '23bab5fe-7c24-4a56-8812-982d919d8cd3' in search application 'Search Service Application' is in a good state and try again. 
>       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchApi..ctor(SearchServiceApplication application) 
>       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.get_SearchApi() 
>       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.CrawlRuleCollection.InitCache() 
>       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.CrawlRuleCollection..ctor(Content parent) 
>       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Content.get_CrawlRules() 
>       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.WebControls.ManageCrawlRulesControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
>       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
>       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
>       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
>       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
>       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
>       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
>       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

And am receiving this [error in Event viewer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125263/application-server-administration-job-failed-for-service-instance-microsoft-offi/125299#125299).

Followed this [article](http://www.social-point.com/sharepoint-2010-event-id-6482-application-server-administration-job-failed-for-service-instance-microsoft-office-server-search-administration-searchserviceinstance), which helped everyone to fix the issue but not me. sadly.

Please someone HELP!!

Comment: Check services on server and make sure the search service is running.

Comment: Recreating the Search Service Application helped me once with the same error.

Comment: Is it an option to create a new Search Service Application?

Comment: I tried all the below options today:-

Comment: I tried all the below options today:-
1. Deleting the existing search service and re-creating with the administrator managed account.
2. Re-running the configuration wizard of SharePoint 2010
3. Changing the application pool to SharePoint Web Services Systems and to SharePoint Web Services Default.
Anyone, please help me with a trick.